# React On Rails SSR "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, server-side-rendering, webpacker, react-on-rails

I am using "react-on-rails" gem for react and rails but i tried to SSR(server side rendering) prerender: true in rails view file. It's give me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined".

react_on_rails = 10.0.2
webpacker = 3.5.3

[image]

Comment: I have not tried this myself, see if this [helps](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/971)